# Why are expressions in the argument part of a function call evaluated even if the function can't be called?

Tags: javascript

I discovered some seemingly odd JavaScript behavior and was wondering if there is a specific reason for it:

The function call `null(console.log('test'))` will throw an error but also log `test`. Shouldn't this expression be only evaluated after it is clear that the function can be called?

I thought it maybe the case that the expression in the argument part is evaluated before the function name. But a function call like `(console.log(1))(console.log(2))` will indeed log fist `1` then `2`.

Comment: The order of evaluation is spelled out in the language specification. [Function calls](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-function-calls) says that the MemberExpression (the thing before the parameters) is evaluated first, then the arguments, and then the function is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, in a dynamic language, the way you determine if an object is callable is by calling it. And you're not allowed to do that until the arguments have been evaluated.

Sure, for a keyword like `null` it is knowable ahead of time that it won't be callable, but that's an unusual case; most of the time, you're loading a variable that might or might not be callable; special casing the interpreter to check for attempts to call non-callable constants is pointless when it shouldn't happen in idiomatic code, and it won't handle a simple case like:

```
var foo = null;
foo(console.log(1));
```

The only other solution is to pre-check for callability at the moment the maybe-callable is evaluated, but that's just adding additional checks that slow down the interpreter, slowing down all code for a tiny benefit that is only realized in pathological code.